# Segment bin string with 'which' statement in R

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, segment

I have tried lots of algorithms on my dataset to perform a clustering and now would love to apply now managerial segmentation with 'which'statements on my data. I was wondering what might makes more sense if I shall do the segment on customer math or on the Years which are lasting from X1-X8.
Doing managerial segmentation on X1-X8 is clear, but I don't know how to do it on the string.

Here is my df:

```
   customer_id customer_math X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
1   15251       10001010      1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0
2   10101       11111111      1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
3   84787       10101010      1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0
```

For instance, I would like to answer the following questions:

1. Customers who had once a "zero" in it
2. Customers who had twice in a row a "zero" in it
3. Customers who left and came back for instance"  --> at least one zero in the string and on ending string 1.

Thank you very much for your feedback!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Q3 is unclear... does it require X8 = 1? Likely a good solution will involve the use of `rle()`

Comment: So you're looking for three different subsets?

Comment: Hi sorry the "for instance" was inappropriate. Yes, three segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly:

```
library(stringr)
q1 <- df[str_count(df$customer_math, "0")==1,]            #exactly one '0' occurrence in string
q2 <- df[grepl("00",df$customer_math),]                   #at least two zeros ina a row - or more, be aware of it, this is simple solution and it won't get only exact 00 occurences, but you can fix it easly^^
q3 <- df[str_count(df$customer_math, "0")>=1 & df$X8==1,] #at least one zero in string and always 1 at the end
```

Comment: Hi Adamm, the last equation q3 did not work. Might it be because I have <fct> values?

Comment: It might be, try `df$X8 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$X8))`